# how to solve Null pointer Exception in onActivityResult method?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, onactivityresult

i found a null pointer exceptions in this code. this exceptions only comes in this Huawei HUAWEI Y6 Pro 2019 (HWMRD-M1), 2816MB RAM, Android 9 device . other device working so so well . how can i solve this problem.

google reporst is below -

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
at droidrocks.com.twitchemotemaker.EmoteActivity.onActivityResult (EmoteActivity.java:28)




@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri PHOTO_DATA = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), PHOTO_DATA);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 112, 112, true);
            emoteImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 56, 56, true);
            emoteImageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 28, 28, true);
            emoteImageView3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Add the full stacktrace.

Comment: what is the 28th line of code? Which line gives error?